# Java TicTacToe game symbols not being placed in right spot

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, methods, char, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to develop a code for a tic tac toe game. I have to use a 2d array and the board must look like this.

```
| _ | _ | _ |
| _ | _ | _ |
| _ | _ | _ |
```

So far I've got the board down and I have it to where I can take input from the user for the row and column they wish to place in. But I'm having trouble with getting the symbol to be placed in the right spot.

When I enter in 1 1 (row 1, col 1) this is the output I get

```
| _ | _ | _ |
| _ x| _ |
| _ | _ | _ |
```

when I need to get this

```
| x | _ | _ |
| _ | _ | _ |
| _ | _ | _ |
```

This is my code that I have so far. Ive tried changing the array to a char type but then I don't know how to get the board to be multiple chars which I would need to get the board to look like the one above.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Let's play Tic-Tac-Toe!");

        String[][] board = new String[3][3];
        

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                board[i][j] ="| _ ";
            }
        }

        printBoard(board);

        boolean playerX = true;

        String symbol = " ";
        if(playerX) {
            symbol = "x";
        } else{
           symbol = "o";
        }

        int userRow = 0;
        int userCol = 0;
        
        while(true){
            System.out.print("Enter row and col");
            userRow = scnr.nextInt();
            userCol = scnr.nextInt();

            if(userRow < 1 || userCol < 1 || userRow > 3 || userCol > 3){
            System.out.println("Please enter valid row and col numbers from 1 to 3:");
                } else if(board[userRow][userCol] != "| _ "){
                    System.out.println("That spot is full!");
                    } else { 
                        break;
                     }
        }
        
        board[userRow][userCol] = symbol;
        printBoard(board);
    }

    public static void printBoard(String[][] board){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println('|');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Separate the board data structure from how it will be displayed. There should be no pipe symbols in your data.... that's a visualisation aspect.

Answer (score 0):

On line 46, you should change this

```java
board[userRow][userCol] = symbol;
```

to this

```java
board[userRow][userCol] = "| " + symbol + " ";
```